# Injective map which on quotients is the inclusion of a direct summand

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

suppose we are given a commutative ring $R$, a principal ideal $I$ and an injective ring map $R \stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} R^n$, which on quotients $R/I \longrightarrow (R/I)^n$ is the inclusion of a direct summand.

**Question:** Can one show that $f$ has to be the inclusion of a direct summand?

If this is too general, what are necessary conditions for something like this to be true?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at a *single* example? $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $I=(2)$ for instance.

Comment: Right, so for instance $\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ given by $1\mapsto (1,2)$ is not the inclusion of a direct summand, but is mod $2$. Thanks.